# Longest distance displayed on screen in kilometers

Tags: android, distance, android-maps-v2

On Google Map Api V2 for Android,
I would like to calculate the longest distance in kilometers displayed on screen (while zoom factor is a parameter) in order to determinate the radius of the smallest circle containing all the map displayed on screen at present time:

That means the distance between the center of the screen and one of the edges.

Is there some Tool I can use to do that ? (Maybe to get the coordinates of one of the edges...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the Projection class (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html)

For example:

```
Projection projection = map.getProjection(); // get map projection
VisibleRegion vr = projection.getVisibleRegion(); //
```

vr now contains the corners of your map, from there you can compute the distances...

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html

It would probably be wise to do this inside an OnCameraChangedListener , to be sure you have valid a projection value